# Ocultar "public" de la URL de Symfony

Tags: apache, symfony5

Ante todo disculparme, porque aunque sé que hay muchas respuestas a mi pregunta, lo cierto, es que al no entender muy bien las respuestas, parece que no consigo hacerlo bien en mi página.
He leido todo esto:
[Symfony](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjd7LiU_uv6AhUphP0HHU8cCT0QFnoECEAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsymfony.com%2Fdoc%2Fcurrent%2Fsetup%2Fweb_server_configuration.html&usg=AOvVaw10QSkt-pPqI2HELQsmvFEV)
[Respuesta 1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjd7LiU_uv6AhUphP0HHU8cCT0QFnoECBoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F68444988%2Fsymfony-5-remove-public-from-url&usg=AOvVaw1WNlJ1-D737XVr9X3EAM8C)
[Respuesta 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjd7LiU_uv6AhUphP0HHU8cCT0QrAIoAHoECBsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F23837933%2Fhow-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel&usg=AOvVaw1n2BqfYccWaAdy4o7ITazb)
[Respuesta 3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjd7LiU_uv6AhUphP0HHU8cCT0QrAIoAXoECBsQAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63567157%2Fhide-public-in-url-symfony-in-subfolder&usg=AOvVaw1xbawdzHp7ybKNtwkDZQLn)

Tengo 2 softwares en mi servidor, un portal (Zikula - Basado en Symfony 5) y un foro (SMF). Estoy actualizando la versión de Zikula a esta nueva versión en Symfony 5, que funciona bajo la carpeta "public". Como tantos otros, quiero ocultar de la URL este subdirectorio para que las URLs sean más amigables e iguales a las que tengo ahora sin actualizar.
Entonces, cada software lo tengo bajo la carpeta /public_html del servidor. Zikula bajo la carpeta "portal" y el foro bajo "foro".

Actualmente, tengo un .htaccess en "/public_html" para redireccionar dominios.

```
RewriteEngine on

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName heroesofmightandmagic.es

Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^heroesofmightandmagic.es$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.heroesofmightandmagic.es$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.heroesofmightandmagic\.es\/portal\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^torredemarfil\.es$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.torredemarfil\.es$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.torredemarfil\.es\/foro\/" [R=301,L]
```

Y sé que tengo otro .htaccess bajo la carpeta de symfony "/public", que es el que viene por defecto entiendo.

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
Options FollowSymlinks

# Allow web access in /public folder
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.2
    Allow from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.4
    Require all granted
</IfModule>

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

# Enable short urls if supported
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn the rewriting engine on
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Y con todo lo leido anteriormente, tengo varias dudas. No sé si las respuestas las tengo que poner en el .htaccess de "public_html" o bajo la de "/public" de symfony.
No sé si tengo que desactivar(eliminar) uno de los 2 .htaccess al aplicar la solución o no.
En fin, como véis, estoy bastante perdido. Si me pudiesen echar una mano.

Estoy haciendo el upgrade en un [sitio de pruebas](http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/zk2to3/public/news/messages/view). Y de ahí lo que quiero es quitar ese "public".

Gracias.

Comment: Por un lado, en el .htaccess que tienes el /public_html seguramente agregando esta línea ya consigues algo: `RewriteRule ^zk2to3/(.*)$ /zk2to3/public/$1`  pero luego tienes que tener en cuenta dos cosas: 1) No sabemos que contiene el .htaccess de public/, por lo tanto quizás haga cosas inesperadas cuando llegue la petición y 2) Los enlaces de las páginas que cuelguen de public/ **no deben llevar el /public** para que funcione bien (eso si el punto 1 no hace nada raro)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He añadido la linea que me has indicado, y sí, algo hace, pero tenemos resultados inesperados como bien dices (esto fue una de mis pruebas). Puedes ver el resultado [aquí](https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/zk2to3/news/messages)
Reescribo el otro .htaccess en el hilo principal para ayudar

Comment: Renombra ese .htaccess y créate otro con estas tres líneas solo: 1) `RewriteEngine On` 2) `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` y 3) `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` a ver si cuela

Comment: Gracias. Me sigue dando un error 404. Puedes ver el resultado del cambio en la página que te indiqué en mi anterior comentario.
Si le añades el "public" sí funciona.

Comment: mmm... ¿tienes algun otro .htaccess intermedio en la carpeta  `/zk2to3/`?  ¿en que carpeta está exactamente el segundo .htaccess?  Es que es raro el mensaje de error que aparece, pues no es el típico de apache, sinó personalizado para Zikula y no acabo de entender porque aparece así (a menos que tengas archivos personalizados 404 en esas carpetas, pero a nivel de .htaccess no parece que llames a ninguno en concreto)

Comment: No, he revisado y no tengo ningún otro .htaccess
Sí, porque ahí ya está intentando de cargar las páginas, pero parecen que por alguna causa, dan error, mientras que en la "public" no...puede que esté relacionado con alguna config de Symfony o similar?.

Comment: He instalado un Zikula "Vainilla" con los mismos cambios que me has indicado (por si era algo de mis modificaciones) en esta otra [URL](https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/zk304/) Si cargo la "home", me redirige a "public". Si cargo otra página sin "public", me da error en Symfony [Ejemplo](https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/zk304/search)

Comment: Vamos a probar otra cosa, solo para salir de dudas. Pasos: 1) Agrega esto al .htaccess de tu public_html/:  `RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/public/$1`  2) Create una carpeta que cuelgue de **public_html** llamada **test** y dentro te creas otra llamada **public**, de tal forma que la ruta sea `public_html/test/public`... 3) Dentro de esa ruta te creas un archivo html simple, por ejemplo, index.html, y le pones algo de contenido. 4) Abres el navegador y te vas [aquí](https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/test/index.html) a ver si se abre o no.  Y me cuentas lo que haya pasado, gracias.

Comment: Pues ya está todo hecho. Y da un error 500, indicando como que algo está mal

Comment: Debe ser algo del .htaccess... comenta esta última línea que has puesto y prueba de nuevo a ver si te sale al menos un error 404 (para librarnos del error 500).  Si te sale el error 404 entonces vuelve a repasar la nueva linea y ponla justo debajo del `RewriteEngine on` por si acaso de la pega con otras reglas.

Comment: Pues nada, no hay forma. He quitado la linea, sale el error 404. Pongo la linea en la segunda linea, bajo ```RewriteEngine on``` y error 500

Comment: Ahora mismo está con la linea ```RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/public/$1```
Y sí, da error 500 al entrar con el public en la URL, pero los permisos de los ficheros son como en el resto, el index.html tiene 0644

Comment: Ah perdona, no te había entendido. He quitado la linea y sí, funciona (puedes verlo entrando en la [pagina](https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/test/public/index.html)

Comment: Esta todo en el hilo inicial de aquí, pero te lo dejo igualmente.
El de [public html] (https://pastebin.com/8asB7uLx)
El de [zk2to3 public] (https://pastebin.com/ZApxT2tS)
Gracias.

Comment: He dejado los originales. Te paso como me dijiste en [pastebin] (https://pastebin.com/cXNraZeg)
He probado en la linea 2 y en la 27
No, es un servidor compartido. Es una web pequeña sin pretensiones (ocio)

Comment: Sí, las lineas 25, 26 y 27 daban error. He dejado solo esas 2 lineas y tampoco, Error 500. 
He probado poniendo esto:
```RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/test/(.*)$ /test/public/$1 ```
Y si funciona, pero hay que poner el public igualmente o te da error 404

Comment: Si escribo esto ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/public/index.html?$1 [L,QSA]``` Me funciona con la URL `https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/test/index.html`

Comment: Si escribo ```RewriteRule ^zk304/(.*)$ zk304/public/$1``` y cargo la URL `http://heroesofmightandmagic.es/zk304/search` me carga symfony, pero algo "va mal" pq no encuentra la ruta.... Es como que interpreta /zk304 como parte de la ruta en symfony

Comment: Bueno, antes de abrir la pregunta aqui, ya abrí ticket a mi hosting y no me ayudaron en nada, solo me dijeron que me busase un desarrollador y le pagase.
Mi hosting funciona bajo cPanel, y la estructura real de mis carpetas te las he mencionado (ambos softwares están bajo la carpeta public_html)
Todo lo que pueda indicarte, me dices y te intento decir, si es que aún no tiraste la toalla :)

Comment: cPanel tiene una parte que indica "Domains", cuando ahí le pongo que el foro está bajo `public_html/foro`, me da error. Tengo que ponerle que está bajo `public_html`o no funciona. Eso es lo que me indicaron desde el hosting, y lo tuve que dejar como estaba con solo `public_html`, aunque este bajo otra carpeta `public_html/foro`

Comment: He borrado algunos comentarios, pues esto parecía un chat y los moderadores nos hubieran migrado todo esto a uno si lo llegan a ver.  Haz lo mismo y deja tan solo los fundamentales para entender la respuesta dada, gracias.

Comment: @Krator porfa borra todos los comentarios que no sean aclaratorios a tu pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

He reproducido tu error en un cPanel y en el archivo del servidor mostraba esto como error 500:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

Así que según parece se estaba redirigiendo continuamente y al cabo de 10 redirecciones aparece el error 500.

Para solucionarlo he puesto esto antes de la regla:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

que impide que una regla rewriteRule pueda ser aplicada si otras reglas se han aplicado antes, por lo tanto tan solo la aplica una vez.

Todo junto sería así:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule "^test/(.*)" "test/public/$1"
```

Prueba y comentamos tu resultado si algo sale mal.

### Otra solución

Consistiría en poner esta línea justo después del `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

que indica que si el archivo existe deje de leer las otras reglas y lo ejecute.  Con eso también evitarás el error 500 debido a las redirecciones internas que hace la propia regla sobre si misma.

En caso de que el archivo no exista porque se encuentre con más reglas que vayan a interpretar esa peticion en otros **.htaccess** que estén en el camino, entonces mejor la primera solución.

Comment: Efectivamente, para el caso simple que hicimos con la carpeta "test" ha funcionado correctamente. Sin embargo, y como sospechaba, algo más le pasa a "Zikula/Symfony", porque da un error de ruta [error](https://www.heroesofmightandmagic.es/zk304/search). Esto se produce pq toma el subdirectorio "zk304" como parte de la ruta, y no debe ser así. A ver si alguien puede ayudarme con esa otra "pata".

Comment: Bueno, al menos hemos avanzado con algo. En cuanto al Symfony, no tengo ni idea, solo veo que automáticamente se generan unos [archivos de configuración](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html) y que seguramente es allí donde debes buscar la cadena **/public** y quitarla a ver si funciona.  Fíjate que en tu pregunta no has aportado nada de Symfony, solo de .htaccess, y sin datos estamos a ciegas igualmente.

Comment: [En este enlace](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-public-directory) tambien explican más cosas sobre eso.  Suerte! (eso si que no voy a reproducirlo... tan solo he tocado Symfony una vez, y ya fue hace una década para arreglar el elevado consumo de recursos que estaba haciendo)

Comment: He encontrado en cPanel el error que da ahora:
`[Mon Oct 24 16:26:07.115902 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 6335:tid 140618806245120] [client 68.183.116.148:50539] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/heroesmi/public_html/zk304/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.php,index.php5,index.php4,index.php3,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.phtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,Default.html,Default.htm,default.html,default.htm,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: No sé si es por el .htaccess que hablamos que está en /zk304/public
Pero es que si elimino este fichero, da Error 500